# how to change text color for legends in primeng charts

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using basic charts in Primeng i.e Line, Bar and Pie chart in my angular 4 app. I would like to change the text color for the legends and x-axis and y-axis texts. I tried setting the options but no[image]t working. Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Please find attached the charts i am getting.

I tried setting the options

typescript:
options: any;
    this.options = {
        legend: {
            fontColor: 'red'
        }
    };

i am using primeng v4.x
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    this.options = {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'white'
            }
        }
    };
```

The documentation for the chart options are available in :
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html